# Syncing tex file and integrated PDF viewer in Kile

Tags: forward-inverse-search, kile

I'm having trouble properly syncing the TeX and PDF files in Kile.
At some point, Kile was properly moving the PDF preview following where I was in the TeX file but then it stopped working at some point (I don't know what changed).
What settings are necessary for the PDF viewer to follow the current location in the TeX file?

I am using XeLaTex compiling in a `build` directory with options `-aux-directory=build -output-directory=build -shell-escape -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %source`.
And, in Kile, I set "Relative dir" to `build` in the advanced options.
If anyone can tell me what I may be doing wrong...

[EDIT: the second part of the question, below, is solved [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/614187/120360)]

Furthermore, I'd like to know if it is possible to jump to the LaTeX code line from the integrated PDF viewer in Kile.
I am specifically looking for the equivalent of TeXMaker "Click to jump to the line (CTRL+Click)" or TexStudio "Go to source": I'm reading the PDF and I want to jump from there to the specific location in the code that is associated to that part of the PDF.
I could not find any hint in [the documentation](https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/kile/kile/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

OK, I can reply to the second part of my question: how to do the inverse search (jump back to the code line).

I had to configure Okular (Settings > Editor then set Editor to Kile) and from then on jumping to the code is done via [Shift+Click](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4153185/5962321).

And this seems to work both with "Forward PDF" and "ViewPDF" so I'm not sure what the difference between the two is...